# I input a value in PrimeReact Autocomplete field but the warning red border does not disappear

Tags: primereact

I have a problem with *PrimeReact AutoComplete* component:

when I marked it as required it works well but when I input a value the **warning red border** **does not disappear**:

First state before insert values for both `name` and `leader` fields:

[image]

and the second state after inserting value for the inputs:

[image]

**As you see the name input field work as I expect but the autocomplete input does not remove red border and the warning text below.**

The code of two inputs:

Autocomplete field:

```
<div className='field col'>
  <span className='p-float-label'>
    <AutoComplete
      id='leader-autocomplete'
      value={leader}
      onChange={(e) => setLeader(e.value)}
      suggestions={filteredUsers}
      completeMethod={searchUser}
      field='leader'
      inputId='leader'
      minLength={3}
      required
      className={classNames({'p-invalid': submitted && !group.leader})}
    ></AutoComplete>
    <label htmlFor='autocomplete'>Leader</label>
  </span>
  {submitted && !group.leader && (
    <small className='p-invalid'>Leader is required.</small>
  )}
</div>
```

And the name input field:

```
<div className='field col'>
  <label htmlFor='title'>Name</label>
  <InputText
    id='name'
    value={group.name}
    onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, 'name')}
    required
    className={classNames({'p-invalid': submitted && !group.name})}
  />
  {submitted && !group.name && <small className='p-invalid'>Name is required.</small>}
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can look at this example it seems to be working fine.  Maybe compare with what you are doing?  https://primereact.org/autocomplete/#hookform

Comment: @Melloware thank you for your advice. I solved my problem. It was my misunderstanding of `Autocomplete` component (`span` and inner `input` IDs). I changed `setLeader` of `onChange` to a function and set `group.leader` inside it.